# Shopify Buy SDK — Add line items error

Tags: javascript, sdk, shopify

I'm using the shopify buy SDK to create a custom storefront:

- I get an error when trying to add a line item
- The example code below all works, except when it hits the 'addLineItems' method: I've checked the parameters and they seem ok.

```js
shopify.checkout.create().then((checkout) => {
  checkoutId = checkout.id
  console.log('checkout id: ' + checkoutId) // Works OK
})

shopify.product.fetchAll().then((products) => {
  lineItemsToAdd = [
    {variantId: products[0].variants[0].id, quantity: 1}
  ]
  console.log('line items to add: ' + lineItemsToAdd) // Works OK
})

shopify.checkout.addLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToAdd).then((checkout) => {
  console.log('checkout line items: ' + checkout.lineItems)
}) // Throws error
```

And the error I get is:

```js
index.js?7327:3705 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkoutLineItemsAdd' of undefined
at eval (index.js?7327:3705)
at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is happening because Javascript is async by nature.

All of your calls executing at the same time and not in consequence. Because of that `checkoutId, lineItemsToAdd` variables are not set when  `addLineItems` is executing.

You need to use promises to create a sequence. You can read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises).  Example of your code with a promise:

```
<script>

const client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
  domain: '-----------------------',
  storefrontAccessToken: '--------'
});
var checkoutPromise = client.checkout.create()
var productPromise = client.product.fetchAll()


Promise.all([checkoutPromise,productPromise]).then(([checkout,products]) => 
{
    var lineItemsToAdd = [
        {variantId: products[0].variants[0].id, quantity: 1}
      ]
    var checkoutId = checkout.id

    console.log('checkout id: ' + checkoutId)       
    console.log('line items to add: ' + lineItemsToAdd)

    client.checkout.addLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToAdd).then((checkout) => {
        console.log('checkout line items: ' + checkout.lineItems)
    })
})
</script>
```

P.S. Code above is [not supported in IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=promise)

Comment: You’ve just made my day. Makes total sense.

Comment: It seems to also work just by nesting the calls I had — is this a good or bad idea?

Comment: Depends on your needs. In your example, you don't have to nest all three calls in one sequence. You can execute first two in parallel and then execute third when previous two calls finished. That what I did with promise.